# visualizar documentos al registrar o actualizar documento

Tags: datagridview

Agradecería si me pudieran ayudar tengo un formulario en el que registro, actualizo y listo documentos sin problemas el inconveniente sucede cuando registro un nuevo documento o actualizo un documento, actualizo el datagridview para que me muestre los datos nuevamente, pero al visualizar el documento (PDF) no me se visualiza si no realizo un registro o una actualización si se visualiza sin problemas , quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que cuando registre o actualice se visualice mis documentos, al parecer al visualizar no actualiza los registros insertados o actualizados como podria identificar si se hizo algún cambio en los registros, de antemano muchas gracias por su apoyo.

Formulario: Para visualizar los documentos al dar clic en el botón documento se visualiza sin problemas el documento pdf, pero cuando actualizo o registro uno nuevo ya no se visualiza

[image: Formulario]

Código del registro de documentos

```
Private Sub btn_Guardar_Documento_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Guardar_Documento.Click

    If txt_Ruta_Archivo.Text = "" Then

        MessageBox.Show("Seleccionar documento", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    ElseIf txt_Titulo_Documento.Text = "" Then

        MessageBox.Show("Ingresar titulo del documento", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    ElseIf CheckBox_Estado_Documento.Checked = False Then

        MessageBox.Show("Activar estado del documento", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    Else

        Documentos.Registrar_Documento()
        Documentos.Generar_Codigo_Documento(txt_Codigo_Documento)
        Documentos.Listar_Filtrar_Documentos(DataGridView_Listar_Documentos, txt_Codigo_Bien_Activo_Documento.Text)

        Limpiar_Campos_Registrar()

    End If

End Sub
```

Registrar documento

```
 Public Sub Registrar_Documento()


    Dim mensaje As String

    Try

        conectarse()

        Dim filePath As String = Form_Gestion_Documentos.txt_Ruta_Archivo.Text
        Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
        Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(fs)
        Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length))
        br.Close()
        fs.Close()


         cmd = New SqlCommand("pa_Registrar_Documento", conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        With cmd.Parameters

            .AddWithValue("@CODIGO_DOCUMENTO", Form_Gestion_Documentos.txt_Codigo_Documento.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@CODIGO_BIEN_ACTIVO", Form_Gestion_Documentos.txt_Codigo_Bien_Activo_Documento.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@TITULO_DOCUMENTO", Form_Gestion_Documentos.txt_Titulo_Documento.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@EXTENSION_DOCUMENTO", Form_Gestion_Documentos.ComboBox_Extension_Documento.SelectedItem)
            .AddWithValue("@DATA_DOCUMENTO", bytes)
            .AddWithValue("@FECHA", Now())
            .AddWithValue("@ESTADO_DOCUMENTO", If(Form_Gestion_Documentos.CheckBox_Estado_Documento.Checked = True, "A", "C"))

            .Add("@MENSAJE", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Direction = 2

        End With

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        mensaje = cmd.Parameters("@MENSAJE").Value.ToString

        MessageBox.Show(mensaje, "MENSAJE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)

    Catch ex As Exception : MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        desconectarse()

    End Try

    desconectarse()

End Sub
```

Listar documentos

```
Public Sub Listar_Filtrar_Documentos(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal documento As String)

    Dim x As Integer 'contador

    Try
        conectarse()

        cmd = New SqlCommand("pa_Listar_Filtrar_Documentos", conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        With cmd.Parameters

            .AddWithValue("@CODIGO_BIEN_ACTIVO", documento)

        End With

        adaptador = New SqlDataAdapter
        adaptador.SelectCommand = cmd
        dt = New DataTable
        adaptador.Fill(dt)
        dgv.DataSource = dt

        x = Form_Gestion_Documentos.DataGridView_Listar_Documentos.Rows.Count
        Form_Gestion_Documentos.Label_Total_Documentos.Text = CStr(x)

    Catch ex As Exception : MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        desconectarse()

    End Try

    desconectarse()

End Sub
```

Visualizar documentos: Al parecer aquí radica el problema no esta actualizando la data del datagridview para que se visualice los pdfs

```
Public Sub Visualizar_Documento()

        Try

        conectarse()

        Dim estado As String = "A"

            Dim codigo_documento As String = Form_Gestion_Documentos.DataGridView_Listar_Documentos.Rows(Form_Gestion_Documentos.DataGridView_Listar_Documentos.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0).Value.ToString()

       
        cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from tb_Documentos where db_codigo_documento like '" & codigo_documento & "' AND db_codigo_bien_activo = '" & Form_Gestion_Documentos.txt_Codigo_Bien_Activo_Documento.Text.Trim & "' AND db_estado_documento = '" & estado & "'", conn)

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        dr.Read()

        If dr.HasRows Then

            'If dr.Item("db_extension_documento") = "PDF" Then
            Dim fileName As String = DirectCast(dr("db_titulo_documento"), String)
            Dim fileData As Byte() = DirectCast(dr("db_data_documento"), Byte())
            Dim sFilePath As String
            sFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()
            System.IO.File.Move(sFilePath, System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(sFilePath, ".pdf"))
            sFilePath = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(sFilePath, ".pdf")
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(sFilePath, fileData)
            Dim act As Action(Of String) = New Action(Of String)(AddressOf OpenPDFFile)
            act.BeginInvoke(sFilePath, Nothing, Nothing)
            dr.Close()

            'Return

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        dr.Close()

    End Try


End Sub
```